# MongoDB PHP Failed to connect to: Timed out after 0 ms

Tags: php, mongodb

I use MongoDB shardings. normally, it works well, but sometimes, failed to connect, and the message shows the error `Timed out after 0ms`.

> Failed to connect to: 192.168.1.10:35050: Timed out after 0 ms

PHP ： 5.3.25

MongoDB： 2.4.7

Comment: It is usually recommended to run a `mongos` process on the default port and other members on alternate ports when testing on a single host. Your question lacks the information of your setup or any evidence any process is using the port you are attempting to connect to.

Comment: mongos: 192.168.1.10:35050, there are two shards , shard1:"rep1/192.168.1.20:35100,192.168.1.22:35101", shard2:"rep2/192.168.1.21:35100,192.168.1.22:35202". I want to connect to the mongos when using php-mongo extension.